# Ext js - Grid is not taking the available space. How do I set its height to take the entire available space in the view?

Tags: extjs

We have a view which has 30% of it as chart and reaming grid. But the grid is not taking the entire available space.

```
    {
                xtype:'gridpanel',
                title: "Sales Report",
                width:'100%',
                height:250,
                itemId:'itemID',
                store:storeForDataByOrgGrid,
                border:true,
                padding: 5,
                scroll: true,
                //forceFit: true,
                viewConfig : {

                },
                columns:[

                ],

                    tools:[
                    {
                        type:'up',
                        tooltip: 'Export to Excel',
                        handler:'excelGenerator'
                    }
                ]



            }
```

Comment: Could you please show some of your code?

Comment: {
     xtype:'gridpanel',
     title: "Update Location Report",
     width:'100%',
     height:250,
     itemId:'ulTop10Grid',
     store:storeForDataByOrgGrid,
     border:true,
     padding: 5,
     scroll: true,
     //forceFit: true,
     viewConfig : {
     
     },
     columns:[
      
     ],
     
      tools:[
      {
       type:'up',
       tooltip: 'Export to Excel',
       handler:'excelGenerator'
      }
     ]
     
     
     
    }

Answer (score 0):

Add the `flex: 1` attribute to the grid and make the component's layout which contains the grid and the chart  as `vbox` using:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox'
    align : 'stretch',
    pack  : 'start',
}
```

Comment: The same thing I do have a problem with one of the other views ...Where the view has some date picker in the 30% of its size and reaming area is occupied by the tree node structure.Here also I want to make my tree node structure to take the entire available space

Comment: {
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    title: '<b>Operators<b>',
    margin:'0 0 0 10',
    width:'50%',
    items:[ {
     xtype: 'treepanel', 
     id:'opsTree',
     store: Tree1,  
     rootVisible: false,
     useArrows: true,     
     width: '100%',
     height: 300,
     tbar:[
      {
       xtype:'textfield',
       id:'searchTextField',
       listeners: {
        change: 'filterOps'
       },
       emptyText:'Search',
       triggers: {
        clearIcon: {
         cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
         handler: 'clearSearchText'
        }
       }
      }
     ]
    }]
   },